# Continuous function, take 2

Tags: limits, continuity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Continuous function, not sure what to do here…](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294297/continuous-function-not-sure-what-to-do-here)

The question is as follows:

f(x)= x if x<1, and x^2 + 1 if x > or = 1.

Let g be a function such that f(x)g(x) is continuous at x=1, and g(1)=2.5 What is lim g(x) as x approaches to 1?

If anyone could solve this problem, and maybe help me understand how to get to the answer, I would be very thankful. I've never been good at math.